# Keep a rectangular frame from racking

Tags: wood, joinery, technique

I have a rectangular frame that I want to keep from flattening into a parallelogram. The frame is 8' x 4' and the members are 4 7/8" high by 2 5/8" thick.

There isn't a particular load that will be pressing it into the shape per se, but I want to prevent this from happening through incidental forces, because this rectangular frame will have some load on its flat side.

I want to avoid having to make corner to corner crossbars because the size of the rectangle makes it difficult to do this and I am also using wood joinery without screws or brackets. I have considered adding supports across each corner.

Is there a better/cleaner way that does not involve any 45° miter of any kind? I feel like there must be something obvious I am missing.

Comment: have you considered and/or rejected gussets?

Comment: @fred_dot_u I haven't rejected them entirely, but the frame is 8 feet by 4 feet, so they may not be ideal (would be pretty large (right?)

Comment: with a frame that size, you are on the right track for bracing, but your restrictions are, um, restrictive. As a layman, I'd be shooting for a gusset minimum size of one foot (five toes) on the short side and two on the long side. Cable bracing almost certainly involves screws. What do you think about cord (tension) bracing on the hypotenuses of the imaginary gussets described in my previous sentence?

Comment: @fred_dot_u thanks a ton for your help; btw do you mean like a piece of cable or line of some kind that would run from gusset hypotenuse to gusset hypotenuse?

Comment: I think you've selected your Best Answer here too quickly, after all there are numerous potential solutions and some can be used in concert, for a belt-and-braces approach (which might be advisable given the size you're dealing with). But we definitely need more detail than just "a frame 8' x 4 feet". What wood? What frame members? Corners mitred? If so case mitres or frame mitres? And by no means least, what is this for?

Comment: @Graphus I've now unselected the answer to give time for more answers. Thank you for your comment. The corners are through mortise and tenon. The material is white oak. Each piece is 4 7/8 inches high by 2 5/8 inches thick.

Comment: Well M&Ts are a good start as they're among the stiffest of all joints, and that's beefy stuff you've made it from! I'm wondering how much racking you're getting right now? If it's fairly minimal I'm thinking simple corner brackets might be enough (steel ones, secured by four screws per) but really these are just a stand-in for gussets and if those are an acceptable option then they'd be the superior choice. They don't have to be huge to be effective since each one doesn't have to act in isolation, they work together as a system with the frame itself. [contd]

Comment: Now a big q for me is what's inside the frame? I presume from the Question that it is currently open, and the frame unsupported in any way (so just sitting on the floor/ground) but if that's not the case please clarify. If you can put a back or bottom into it any racking worries go away.

Comment: @Graphus thank you so much for all this helpful information. The frame will support a flat top whereupon a mattress will be placed. I'm actually going to be placing 3/4" inch plywood inside the frame flush to the edges, sat down 3/4" on a glued rail with half-lapped crossbars underneath, just nothing corner to corner, so technically this entire thing is already sound, but when I was thinking through the process I realized that without this plywood the whole thing could collapse, and even though I have the plywood so it's not a problem, it made me want to learn more about this problem.

Comment: OK then, in that case I think there's little of concern except if/when it may be needed to move the frame 'empty' in the future. With that plywood panel in place, even unfixed, there's not much worry of this racking (because the frame basically has nowhere to go). But if the ply is screwed down then racking becomes literally impossible. If you did want to strengthen the frame for moving to a new house/apartment you could consider screwing on temporary gussets (nothing fancy, scraps of ply will do) on the bottom to reinforce it just for handling, then simply take them off once at the new home.

Comment: @Graphus thanks again - that's perfect. Also, I did not know it was called racking, so that's good to know also.

Comment: @orokusaki this is why it's important to include _context_ in your question. If you'd provided the info up front that this was a bed support frame and was going to be filled with plywood, you'd have had an answer in no time. One small piece out of the puzzle, totally out of context, gives others very little to work with and makes it much harder to address the situation.

Comment: @FreeMan the truth of the matter was that I didn't really have an actual problem, because I had already solved it with the plywood sheet, so I was more wanting to understand the general ways of avoiding this racking problem without a specific scenario, so that I would get responses back that were more generally useful, rather than very specific hacks for a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

The option of using cabling or cording of some sort is best presented with an image, curiously enough, to scale:

[image: corded frame support]

The blue lines are cord, passed through holes drilled at the intersections of the frame. One could get away with a single continuous piece, but unless it's secured to the frame, you'll still have undesirable flexibility in the frame. Additional lines could be run, the placement doesn't have to match the drawing. This is presented as an option in the comments discussion, but could be a solution within the restrictions.

Wire cable or non-stretchy cord would be stronger. Non-stretchy cord is also known as Spectra and sometimes UHMWPE.

Comment: Thanks again Fred, one more quick question: are there any other kinds of geometric solutions to this problem that don't involve corner braces of any kind?

Comment: corner braces are effective because they create triangles. A triangle resists deformation more than just about any other geometric shape. You could avoid the corners by making the entire top and side a triangle, that is running a diagonal from one corner to the other, but it's still a corner brace.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using a strong joint such as a half lap, or a mortise and tenon will be about as strong as if it were a single piece of wood.  Think gate construction.  Gates are different in that they have all the weight on one side, thus they need a diagonal brace to transfer some of the load.  If your frame is supported on both sides, and is made with quality, tight fitting joinery, I wouldn't expect any racking at all.

Comment: That's good to hear. Thank you for your answer.